# Can Oracle ADF access SQL Server apart from Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, mssql-jdbc

I need some inputs on features of ADF. As we are thinking of opting to use this technology understanding its features.

How can we access data in SQL Server from ADF? Is ADF designed only for Oracle databases?

Please share your knowledge and help.

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/multidatabaseapp-085183.html

Comment: You connect to any database with a JDBC data source, so not a problem. But the question to ask is why start a new project today with a aging server side tech stack of yesteryear's?

Answer (score 0):

Applications built with the fusion technology stack (ADF business components, ADF controller, ADF Faces)  are supported with Oracle, SQL Server, DB2 and a number of other database; the document [Jdeveloper Certification information](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/index-091111.html#Databases) contains the full list

[Click here for reference](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/multidatabaseapp-085183.html)